# How to work with formula objects in R

Tags: r

I am trying to learn how to make my own functions with `formula` objects. I am mostly confused with how to parse them.

Lets say I have the following

```
gigl <- function(formula, data, family = gaussian())
```

Using the R dataset `BOD`

```
> BOD
  Time demand
1    1    8.3
2    2   10.3
3    3   19.0
4    4   16.0
5    5   15.6
6    7   19.8
```

It is easy to fit a linear model with `lm`

```
>lm(Time~demand, data=BOD)
Call:
lm(formula = Time ~ demand)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       demand  
    -1.8905       0.3746
```

How can I make my own function by parsing a `formula`?

For example if I had

```
>gigl(Time~demand, data=BOD)
```

How can I parse the components? I don't really care what the function `gigl` does. I just want to know how to work with the `formula`.

### Edit

Due to questions about a concrete example lets try the following:

Say that I want to use the inputs from a formula to build a `cor()` matrix. So from the above I would see the result of `cor(Time,demand)` and if more variables were added I would see the complete `cor()` of all inputs.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit about what you want to do with this function? Why do you specifically want to use a formula?

Comment: Formulas are really just collections of symbols. You can walk through them using list style extractors, eg `(a~b)[[3]]` returns `b`. It would be more helpful if you could give a more concrete example of what you want to do.

Comment: what would the formula look like if there were more variables? `a ~ b+c+d` ?  Would the result be the full correlation matrix of a, b, c, d?  if so, is there a distinction between the variable on the LHS of the formula and those on the RHS?

Comment: There is no distinction in this example. It is probably not the best example. Go ahead a make your own example if you would like. I just want to learn how to manipulate `formula` objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rlang` package can make it easier to work with formulas in the tidyeval paradigm. For example you can do

```
library(rlang)

mycor <- function(form, data) {
  v1 <- f_lhs(form)  
  v2 <- f_rhs(form)
  d <- enquo(data)
  qq <- expr(with(!!d, cor(!!v1, !!v2)))
  eval_tidy(qq)

}

mycor(disp~drat, mtcars)
# [1] -0.7102139

with(mtcars, cor(disp, drat))
# [1] -0.7102139
```

The `f_lhs/f_rhs`  functions help to extract the left-hand side and right-hand side respectively. Then we can use `quo()` and the `!!` operator to re-assemble those piece into a new function call. Then we evaluate that new function call with `eval_tidy`.

Comment: It seems odd to me that `!!` is required. What purpose does that fill?

Comment: It replaces a variable name in a call with the value in that variable when that type of expansion normally doesn’t happen. See: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rlang/vignettes/tidy-evaluation.html

Comment: The code here looks up free variables in the parent but normally when using this style of function free variables are looked up in the formula's environment.  For example,  in `X <- 0; f <- function() { X <- 1; mycor(disp ~ drat^X + X, mtcars) }; f()` it will use drat^0 returning NA but should have used `drat^1` since the formula is defined in `f` hence its environment is within `f`.

Comment: Good point @G.Grothendieck. A maybe a better translation would be to use `qq <- expr(...)` rather than `quo()` and `eval_tidy(qq, env=environment(form))`. That would make your example work. I think the fact that formulas capture environments tends to surprise people rather than do what they expect sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a function that takes a formula and transforms it into a call to the `cor()` function, then evaluates that call in an environment consisting of the data ...

```
f <- function(form,data) {
    form[[1]] <- quote(cor)
    eval(form,data)
}
f(demand~Time,BOD)
## [1] 0.8030693
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to do, but you could take a look at the `terms` of a formula:

```
fm <- formula(Time ~ demand);
tms <- terms(fm);
tms;
#Time ~ demand
#attr(,"variables")
#list(Time, demand)
#attr(,"factors")
#       demand
#Time        0
#demand      1
#attr(,"term.labels")
#[1] "demand"
#attr(,"order")
#[1] 1
#attr(,"intercept")
#[1] 1
#attr(,"response")
#[1] 1
#attr(,".Environment")
#<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

From `tms` you could extract relevant entries and attributes. For example,

```
attr(tms, "variables");
#list(Time, demand)
```

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that two variables are used (expressions are not allowed).  Assuming  that the two variables are in the formula and that they can appear on the right or left or both, `all.vars` which gets the variable names and `get_all_vars` which gets the content can be useful:

```
gig1 <- function(formula, data) cor(data[all.vars(formula)])

gig1(demand ~ Time, BOD)
```

giving:

```
          demand      Time
demand 1.0000000 0.8030693
Time   0.8030693 1.0000000
```

or

```
gig2 <- function(formula, data) cor(get_all_vars(formula, data))

gig2(demand ~ Time, BOD)
```

giving:

```
          demand      Time
demand 1.0000000 0.8030693
Time   0.8030693 1.0000000
```

You might want to look at the source of `lm` and the Formula package for more ideas.