# Correctly parse "formula" object in R

Tags: r, string, parsing, formula

How can I parse an R formula object (`fo`) correctly (i.e., not turning it into a string when parsing)?

Let's say I have the following:

```
## Creating a formula object
fo <- y ~ x1 + x2 | 0 + z1 + z2 + z3 + z4 + z5

class(fo)
##[1] "formula"

typeof(fo)
##[1] "language"

strsplit(fo, split='|', fixed=TRUE)
##Error in strsplit(fo, split = "|", fixed = TRUE) : non-character argument
```

Hopefully, I want to parse it into three atomic vectors:

1. Dependent variable: `c("y")`.
2. Regressors: `c("x1", "x2")`.
3. Others: `c("z1", "z2", "z3", "z4", "z5")` (excluding the `0`).

Comment: [How to work with formula objects in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48796726/903061) should give you a decent start, though it doesn't have the `|` terms.

Comment: Thank you, @GregorThomas it was useful to read! However, my problem was directly related to a three-part formula-style using the `|` symbol.-

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tree structure of the formula breaks down as follows:

- top level: `~`( y, response)

Internally, this is a list-like object where the first element is the operator (`~`), the second element is the first argument, and the third element is the third argument.

So `deparse(fo[[2]])` gets you "y"

- next level (response): `|` (x1+x2, 0 + ...). Same general structure (first element is the operator `|`, second element is the first arg, third element is the second arg)

so `fo[[c(3,2)]]` gets `x1+x2`.

```
all.vars(fo[[c(3,2)]])
```

gets the variables to the left of the bar

```
all.vars(fo[[c(3,3)]])
```

gets the variables to the right of the bar

This gets considerably trickier if you want to extract *terms* rather than variables; for example `all.vars(quote(log(x))` gets "x", not "log(x)"

Possibly useful, you can also use `lobster::ast()` to display the abstract syntax tree (AST):

```
> lobstr::ast(y ~ x1 + x2 | 0 + z1 + z2 + z3 + z4 + z5)
█─`~` 
├─y 
└─█─`|` 
  ├─█─`+` 
  │ ├─x1 
  │ └─x2 
  └─█─`+` 
    ├─█─`+` 
    │ ├─█─`+` 
    │ │ ├─█─`+` 
    │ │ │ ├─█─`+` 
    │ │ │ │ ├─0 
    │ │ │ │ └─z1 
    │ │ │ └─z2 
    │ │ └─z3 
    │ └─z4 
    └─z5
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, @BenBolker, exactly what I needed. Additionally, probably for future readers would be useful to know that the first symbol of the formula is at the beginning when parsing. In other words,`fo[[c(3,1)]]` will provide `|`. Best!